# webbrowser DocumentText does not update on form submit

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I have a website which takes username as input and displays some data.
The task is to create an application which can perform the following steps:
1. Open the website.
2. Enter use details and submit form.
3. Retrieve data.
I am using webBrowser control to interact with web elements.Here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        // Supress the java script errors on the screen 
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        bool complete = false;
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate
        {
            if (complete)
                return;
            complete = true;
            this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
            {
                System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                {
                    var elemList = GetElementsByIdNameContains(webBrowser1, "input", "txtEmpNo");
                    var inputBox = elemList[0];
                    var emp_id = "621999";
                    var errorMsg = "Searched Employee " + emp_id + " doesnt not exist.";
                    inputBox.InnerText = emp_id;
                    var elemList1 = GetElementsByIdNameContains(webBrowser1, "input", "btnSubmit");
                    var submitButton = elemList1[0];
                    submitButton.InvokeMember("Click");
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
        StringBuilder rowData = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@id,'_grdvwAttendance')]"))
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                // TODO: Need to format the output.
                rowData.Clear();
                foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                {
                    rowData.Append(cell.InnerText + "");
                }
                listBox1.Items.Add(rowData);
            }

                 }, null);
            });
        };
        webBrowser1.Navigate("SomeURl");

    }
```

After invoking "Click" the webbrowser1.DocumentText doesn't get updated and the code throws exception on line foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@id,'_grdvwAttendance')]")) since it is not able to find the element on the page.
Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are trying to get the content prior to it is completing (i.e before post method returning the result) submit request and response. Give sometime after invoking submit "Click" option and try. Otherwise you can check the document completed status and check for the element.